# ADSI fails with error 8007203a after Hyper-V failover cluster live migration

Tags: hyper-v, adsi, failovercluster

I have a very weird problem.

We have a Hyper-V failover cluster, where some guest VMs start to show specific problems after a live migration.

In each case, the live migration mostly works, but after it has been migrated, we can't log into some software (our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com)) any more.  The SSPI handshake succeeds, we can RDP to the image, so it's not networking.

But ADSI fails to open a search object to retrieve a user object, and gives error 8007203A.

Since networking is working, SSPI is working, obviously domain connectivity is working to some degree, but the ADSI failure is very perplexing.

Has anyone else seen this?  I feel it's most likely a bug in Windows, but we have been seeing this for over 18 months now - since we set up the cluster.

P.s. all hosts and VMs are 2k12R2 fully patched.
P.p.s. all VM MACs are fixed.

Comment: One other thing I just noticed.  All machines that show this problem are dual-homed (2 NICs), and in the problem state, the internal adapter on each is showing as unknown network.  This may be a firewall issue brought about by re-starting the network adapters.  I have to disable the external adapter before I can restart the internal adapter successfully (it only then gets detected as a domain adapter).

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like I found the answer.

Problem is NLA reclassified the domain network adapter after a live migrate, and set it to an unidentified network.  This then kicked in the firewall to block ADSI.

thanks to [this blog](http://evansblog.thebarrs.info/2013/02/windows-server-force-your-network.html) I was able to force NLA to view the adapter as a domain adapter (by adding a domain DNS suffix to the adapter), and the problem is solved.  Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: spoke too soon. I'm sure it's the NLA problem, I have to disable the external adapter after a live migration before bouncing the internal one for it to discover it's a domain network.  If the external adapter is enabled, then it always fails to identify the internal adapter.  Looks like some kind of broadcast issue going out both adapters.  I've seen posts saying they have the issue the other way (external adapter discovered as internal), probably relates to binding order, and which IP is deemed to be the computer.